# Can I use a dict. with a function "format"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have this:

```
>>> templ = "{aa} fd3443fds {bb} 543gfdgf {cc}"
>>> d1 = {"aa": "this is aa", "bb": "this is bb33", "cc": "this is cc5222"}
```

What's the easiest way to replace the values in {} in `templ` with the corresponding values in "d1", preferably using the function "format" of String?

Comment: Joota, do you mean `String` or `str`? I don't know what a `String` is.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a template string `templ` and a dictionary `d1`, you can fill in the template variables thusly:

```
result = templ.format(**d1)
```

If you have an object `d1` with attributes `d1.aa`, `d1.bb`, etc:

```
class Class1: pass
d1 = Class1()
d1.aa = d1.bb = d1.cc = 'hello'
```

then you could rewrite your template string:

```
templ = "{0.aa} fd3443fds {0.bb} 543gfdgf {0.cc}"
result = templ.format(d1)
```

or you may be able to use `vars(d1)`:

```
templ = "{aa} fd3443fds {bb} 543gfdgf {cc}"
result = templ.format(**vars(d1))
```

Comment: how can I do that for the attributes of an instance? in other words, if d1 is an instance of some Class1 and it has attributes "aa", "bb" and "cc". Passing it as-is throws an exception.

Comment: @Joota - Try using `.format(**vars(d1))`. See my recent edit.

Comment: FYI, in modern Python, `result = templ.format(**d1)` can be done with [`str.format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) to support arbitrary non-`dict` objects as long as they support the mapping protocol by doing `result = templ.format_map(d1)`. At one point, this was also necessary for `dict` subclasses, but it looks like that's not the case in 3.5 at least (`'{a},{b}',format(**defaultdict(lambda: 'foo'))` produces `'foo,foo'` instead of erroring out, indicating the `defaultdict` status isn't lost).